# Пользуется ли популярностью Basic HTTP-аутентификация,Digest HTTP-аутентификация?

Tags: php

Пользуется ли популярностью Basic HTTP-аутентификация,Digest HTTP-аутентификация?

Или лучше свою версию аутентификации сделать, потом как эти публичные, давно уже под микроскопом изучили тем кому это надо, и легко обходят их?

Comment: Если вы про те, что на уровне http то ими не пользуются потому что в дизайн не вписывается окошко которое отображает браузер.

Comment: Это смотря где и смотря какие возможности у сервера|браузера Выбор на само м деле не большой. Form-based например в интернете используется, потому что, как сказал Mike, другое не вписывается в дизайн. В корпоративной сети можно замутить NTML или даже при определённых обстоятельствах kerberos

Comment: ответ зависит от того, что понимать под "популярностью". и под "легко". basic и digest "обойти" нельзя. Они небезопасны по другим причинам - которые легко нивелируются использованием https.